# Why JArray.Parse(json_array) gives me "{" in front of the result?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Why JArray.Parse(json_array) gives me "{" in front of the result? (it's like an object)
What I missed?

```
 string _s = "[{\"person\": { \"b2b_pid\": \"157\"} }]";
 JArray _j = JArray.Parse(_s);
```

_j returns:

```
{[
   {
     "person": {
         "b2b_pid": "157"
       }
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well, [I can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FKWU1)

Comment: It doesn't, the Visual Studio debugger adds that for some reason when visualizing the `JArray` for you.  Try printing to the console in the Immediate Window (or from your code, as shown in the fiddle above) to see the JSON without any visualization tweaks.

Comment: code seems ok. use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string _s = "[{\"person\": { \"b2b_pid\": \"157\"} }]";
```

Simply because you are not passing grammatically correct json object.
in some cases,array cannot be the root of a json object,you have to use dictionary to wrap the array even when you only have one array in your json object.

PS: I notice there is new standard that array top lier is supported.However,be careful of code compatibility.

C# statement `JArray.Parse(_s);` is adequate intelligent to try to fix your json issue While Key missing.